# Get all fields from model that are of specific type in django

Tags: python, django

How to get all fields from specific model of some type?

E.g. I want to get all fields that are PositiveIntegerField, from my model.
How to do it?

Reason why I am asking this is because I have following code:

```
from django import forms
from hzmo_web.apps.hzmo.models import Report

class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Report

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(ReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.fields['osiguranika'].widget.attrs['class']   = 'biggerWidth'
        self.fields['korisnika'].widget.attrs['class']     = 'biggerWidth'
        self.fields['sredstva'].widget.attrs['class']       = 'biggerWidth'
        self.fields['dzd_korisnika'].widget.attrs['class']  = 'biggerWidth'
        self.fields['dzd_djece'].widget.attrs['class']      = 'biggerWidth'
        self.fields['dzd_isplata'].widget.attrs['class']    = 'biggerWidth'
```

All these fields are of type PositiveIntegerField so I want to write some loop to make code shorter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably these fields has the same form Field, you can check that:

```
for field in self.fields:
    if isinstance(field, forms.IntegerField):
        field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'biggerWidth'
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to do this in a try/except block if you have fields in the form that do not exist in your model.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    super(ReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

    for field in self.fields.keys():
        if self._meta.model._meta.get_field(field).get_internal_type()=='PositiveIntegerField':
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs['class']='biggerWidth'
```